# How to make a countdown?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a countdown. I don't see how exactly I can make a countdown. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code does what you tell it. You say in onStart:

```
end.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 4);
end.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);
```

which tells the system you want a countdown starting at 4 minutes and 4 seconds. Instead, do:

```
end.add(Calendar.SECOND, 45);
```

**EDIT**

Took a while to understand what you meant. First, go to github and copy TickTockView into your own project. Remove the dependency to the original project. Open the file and in onDraw, change:

```
    if (mCircleDuration == DURATION_TOTAL && mStartTime != null) {
        long totalTime = mEndTime.getTimeInMillis() - mStartTime.getTimeInMillis();
        float percentage = (((float) mTimeRemaining) / ((float) totalTime));
        angle = 360f * percentage;
    }
```

to:

```
    if (mCircleDuration == DURATION_TOTAL && mStartTime != null) {
        long totalTime = mEndTime.getTimeInMillis() - mStartTime.getTimeInMillis();
        float percentage = (((float) mTimeRemaining) / ((float) 45000));//45000(ms) = 45 seconds
        angle = 360f * percentage;
    }
```

In your xml file where the circle is defined, add:

```
app:tickCircleDuration="total_time"
```

And by doing that, you only need to change totalTime in onDraw in the TickTockView. Remember to update the package name in the XML file to point to the place you saved the file, not the original project.

For reference, [this](https://github.com/BCGDV-ASIA/android-widget-ticktock/blob/master/ticktock/src/main/java/com/bcgdv/asia/lib/ticktock/TickTockView.java) is the file you should copy

Comment: That's not what I meant. My problem is that the circle doesn't make a full cycle in 45 seconds. I will update the question with a GIF now.

Comment: It doesn't make a full cycle in 45 seconds because you tell it to count down from four minutes and 5 seconds. Or 240 seconds. It cannot do a cycle in 45 seconds when your cycle requested is 245 seconds total.

Comment: The GIF does not explain anything more than the image

Comment: And if what you want is the blue circle to go around every 45 seconds, but the max time to be something else you have to describe it.

Comment: Yes, I want the blue circle to go around every 45 seconds. That's why I included a link to the original code. Can you help me find out how to do it? Look at the GIF again.

Comment: The link you linked to at the first of the post, https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKjYd.gif <- this thing does not complete a full cycle in 45 seconds. The blue bar would be closer to the start in that case. To answer you I have to break down your question. "I  don't see how exactly I can make a 45 second countdown." Solution: set the time to 45 seconds and not 4 minutes and 5 seconds!

Comment: I updated the link. Check out the original code and help me :)

Comment: Let me do some research and I will update the answer

Comment: I updated the answer. I haven't tested it though, but it should work in theory

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where is `totalTime` originally defined?

Comment: As defined in the xml file? If you mean total_time(in xml file) t is an integer defined as a constant in TickTockView. If you mean totalTIme in java file where it was changed to 45000 it is the total time. The time you set to the countdown to. Total time, if the time is 1 minute, is 60000ms.

Comment: Excellent support.

Comment: I encountered another problem. How can I show only the seconds (without hours and minutes) in the circular countdown?

Comment: See this: http://pastebin.com/3W4XhN5r Answer was too long to have in the comments

Comment: With your new code, the app just crashes... Please see what's wrong. Thanks for your reply though!

Comment: Create a new paste on pastebin(linked above)(or any other paste service) with the stacktrace

Comment: `E/UncaughtException: java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier: 5$s` error at this line: `return String.format("%2$02d%5$s %3$02d%6$s",
                            minutes,
                            seconds,
                            "m",
                            "s");`

Comment: I am not very familiar with formatting of strings in this way. One way to do it is to not format it, and simply change the string.format line to: `return minutes + "m " + seconds + "s"`

Answer (score 2):

The good way is to use [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) class provided by Android for downward counting in time. I have recently used it in my game and is simple in use. First you

```
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(45000, 1000) {

      // 45000 milliseconds countdown and 1000 milliseconds decrement at each tick.

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

         //you can change your UI here based on time

     }

     public void onFinish() {

          // you can define something to happen when timer ends.

     }
  };

timer.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the below code into

```
    Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
    end.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 4);
    end.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);
```

into

```
    Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
    end.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);//O minute
    end.add(Calendar.SECOND, 45);//45 second
```